# Debug assertion failed, vector subscript out of range, C++, PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I know similar questions have been posted several times, but none of the topics helps me in my case. I am working with PCL (Point Cloud Library) and having issues with a step called *Correspondence Grouping.* I've been using a lot of code from  [this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php), I only reorganized it into several classes. My problem occurs in the line 322. I get the *Debug assertion failed* message, mentioned in the title (see below)

[image].

I've been fighting this for a good couple of days now and I can't see the possible cause. I can step into the header files of PCL, but I get this error message immediately after I try to step into `recognize()`. It looks like it must be a problem with the misuse of `operator[]` of `std::vector` in the PCL itself, but this seems silly and most likely it's my fault somewhere. What could be the cause of that? The parameters `transformations` and `clusteredCorresponcences` are just output parameters and the method `clear()` is invoked on them at the very beginning of `recognize()`. But anyway, they are declared in the same scope, like this:

```
// Object for storing the clustered correspondences.
std::vector<pcl::Correspondences> clusteredCorrespondences;
// Object for storing the transformations (rotation plus translation).
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix4f, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix4f> > transformations;
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why not click the button on that dialog box that will allow you to debug and see which vector is out of bounds?  You mentioned two vectors, which indicates you haven't investigated which one is giving you this error.

Comment: Maybe you should use the debug build of the library and then use the debugger. I just cannot see why you aren't able to access the source code, because the source of the library is open. Look this https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/recognition

Comment: *I can't step into the recognize() method, because PCL is an external library and the compiler doesn't allow me* -- Please get the source code, recompile that library with debugging options turned on, and rerun your test.  Then you will be able to step into the functions.

Comment: Well, it seems I can indeed step into the header files with the debugger, but when I try to step into this `recognize()` method, I get the error immediately. The definition of that method is [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/hough__3d_8hpp_source.html) in line 342

Comment: I've edited the main post to avoid further confusion

Comment: You can recompile the source code and produce the library with debugging information and optimizations turned off.  Then you will be able to step into the function.  Second, what if `grouping_` is an invalid instance?  This code you're showing us is called within class code, and if the instance of that class is invalid, then all bets are off as to what will happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think grouping_ should be valid, [this](http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7093/FoSuyk.png) is how it looks before that critical call

Comment: Even if `grouping_` is valid, you should make sure that the input cloud and scene are properly set. There should be defaults for the thresholds, but the indexing error can be caused by invalid input cloud, reference points, scene points, or the correspondences. Please make sure that the information set for the `grouping_` in the following functions are valid.

    `grouping_.setInputCloud (...);
    grouping_.setInputRf (...);
    grouping_.setSceneCloud (...);
    grouping_.setSceneRf (...);
   grouping_.setModelSceneCorrespondences (...);`